# Using VBA in Excel to sort a table without the table's name

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to create macro whose purpose is simply to sort a table in ascending order. I know it seems like a lot of work to save a couple of clicks, but I need it as part of a larger macro, the rest of which already works. Using the record function, I got this.

```
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Sort. _
    SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Sort. _
    SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[Column1]]"), SortOn:= _
    xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

The above code does work, but I would like to do this without having to reference the table name specifically, because that may change depending on where I'm using it. I wanted to use something like this

```
Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1).Range
```

which as far as I can tell, should point to the same range as
    `Table1[[#All],[Column1]]`, but VBA doesn't like it. It errors out with "object doesn't support this property or method". I'm fairly confident in using `ListObjects(1)` because there should only ever be one table on the sheet.

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is `Sheets("Sheet1").ListObject(1).ListColumns(1).Range` equivalent to `Table1[[#All],[Column1]]`?
3. Is there an easier way to sort a table using VBA?

Update: Thanks Chris for the answer; and, I also realized later that I could just rename the table at the start of the script and avoid this whole mess.

Comment: Did you try `Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects(0)...`  The ListObjects Collection may be zero based.

Comment: It isn't zero based.  I tested it.  But the line you are trying to use with `.Range` at the end isn't doing anything.  What is the rest of that line?  I was able to get this to work `debug.print Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1).Range.Address`

Comment: Sorry, that line was just a representation of code that should point to a range that is the first column of the first table. It isn't actually a stand alone line in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested this, it works provided `Table1` is the first or only ListObject on the sheet, and `Column1` is the first column

```
Sub Demo()
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects(1).Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add _
          Key:=Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1).Range, _
          SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
          Order:=xlAscending, _
          DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the help. I'm not sure what I did wrong, but that looks like exactly the thing I was trying to do.